# return a variable from a function javascript

Tags: javascript, return

how do I return a variable from a function and assign it to an object as a property? I wrote this code but it says that the object property is undefined

```
var ahoy = (function yes() {
    var mp = {};

    function oh() {
        var greeting = "hello";
        var advoir = "goodbye";
    }
    return {
        greeting: greeting,
        advoir: advoir
    };
    oh();
    mp.greeting = greeting;
    mp.advoir = advoir;
    console.log(mp.greeting);
    console.log(mp.advoir);
});
ahoy();
```

Comment: `greeting` and `advoir` are defined in function `oh` - so are not "visible" where you try to return them

Comment: also, you'll never get past the return statement - because, well, a return ends a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here arises from the fact that the `ahoy` function does not have access to the variables in the scope of `oh`.

```
function oh() {
    var greeting = "hello";
    var advoir = "goodbye";

    console.log(greeting);  // "hello"
}

oh();
console.log(greeting);  // undefined
```

`greeting` is local to the scope of `oh` since it is declared inside of `oh`, and is thus not accessible outside of that function. Instead, this would work:

```
var greeting;
console.log(greeting);  // undefined

function oh() {
    greeting = "hello";
    console.log(greeting);  // "hello"
}

console.log(greeting);  // undefined
oh();
console.log(greeting);  // "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

move return statement to the bottom. define greeting outside of the oh function(define with var mp)

Answer (score 0):

I can see few issues in your code:-

1. You are assigning "hello" to greeting and "goodbye" to advoir in function oh() and return in outside that function.
2. Now say even if you put return inside the function oh(), your greeting and advoir would be returned, but you are not capturing the output and thus greeting shows undefined.

You can try following:-

```
var ahoy = (function yes() {

    function oh() {
        var mp={
            greeting:'greeting',
          advoir:'advoir'
        }
        return mp;
    }

    mp=oh();
    var greeting = mp.greeting;
    var advoir = mp.advoir;
    console.log(mp.greeting);
    console.log(mp.advoir);
});
ahoy();
```

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/spuy51rx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing a function, you can just define the variables and return the object all at once

```
var ahoy = (function yes() {
   return {
        greeting: "hello",
        advoir: "goodbye"
    };
});
ahoy();
console.log(ahoy());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ahoy = (function yes() {
  var mp = {};

  // declare the variable outside of function oh
    var greeting, advoir;

  function oh() {
    greeting = "hello";
    advoir = "goodbye";
  }

  oh();
  mp.greeting = greeting;
  mp.advoir = advoir;
  console.log(mp.greeting);
  console.log(mp.advoir);

  // move return statement to end of function
  return {
    greeting: greeting,
    advoir: advoir
  };      
});

ahoy();
```